# Can't open some sheet tabs within a qvw

Tags: business-intelligence, qlikview, qliksense

In my QlikView document, when in the web view, i cant open some sheet tabs.

Some open fine, others don't seem to have any link on them.

These are the main tabs along the top and the properties are the same between one that works and one that doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stuck with a similar problem in the future.

This was strangely the white space around one of my text boxes exceeded the page (Y pos of -25) which was "on top" of the tabs that didn't work, even though visually it wasnt.